# Adding street names to Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I'm brand new to ArcGIS and I want to create a map for the county conservation board I'm interning at. Specifically right now, I need to add the street names on a map of black hawk county for my boss to take to the board meeting (my other bosses). I have a layer of the actually streets, but I need to label them. I know there is a simple solution to this, but like I said, I am brand new to this world.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on layer in table of contents, click Labels tab, click "label features in this layer" check box. Continue on to play with fonts, sizes, placement properties, etc. as your heart so desires. Be sure to choose the correct field from which to draw labels by using the drop down menu following "Label Field:" Depending on your data there could be different naming conventions stored in different fields, such as NAME_LONG (i.e., W 5th Avenue) vs. NAME (i.e., 5th).

[image: Layer Properties]

Comment: Tip: For Displaying Street Names go into the Placement Properties (shown above) and select Street Placement in the General box.